# Conditional loop in python using pandas

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

The below code snippet containing conditional statements is not working as expected. It's returning all 0s for usage['knozo'] where it should contain 1s as well for some rows. Can someone figure out where am I going wrong in this loop/condition?

```
for i in range(0,len(usage)):
    for j in range(0,len(knozo)):
        if usage['key_usage'].iloc[i] == knozo['key_knozo'].iloc[j]:
            usage['knozo'] = 1
        else:
            usage['knozo'] = 0
            break
```

Comment: that means the conditional you have is always false.  So Id start with looking at those 2 variables independently to see whats going on.  Maybe add a print statement? `print("{} == {} => {}".format(a,b,a==b))` where a and b are those 2 condition parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You could try replacing

```
if usage['key_usage'].iloc[i] == knozo['key_knozo'].iloc[j]:
```

with

```
if usage.at[i, 'key_usage'] == konzo.at[j, 'key_konzo']:
```

edit: also, doing `usage['konzo'] = 0` will fill the entire series with that value, so the last condition you evaluate happens to be 0, and you're filling the entire dataframe. You need to specify which element you want to change.